# How to change table cell background color using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

By clicking the button I need to change the background color from `<td>Emil</td>` to red. When clicking again, the previous cell must turn white and the next cell `<td>Tobias</td>` turns red. And so on until the end.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/styles.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <button>Change cell color</button>
      <table id="table">
        <tr>
          <th>Person 1</th>
          <th>Person 2</th>
          <th>Person 3</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Emil</td>
          <td>Tobias</td>
          <td>Linus</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Note**: I found code in jsfiddle in jQuery, however, I need to do it in JavaScript

https://jsfiddle.net/59kh2x0r/

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: toggle a class....

Comment: jQuery **IS** Javascript ......

Answer (score -1):

maybe this answer can solved your problem

```js
<html>
<head>
<script>
        function changeFont(color){
            document.getElementById("miTabla").style.color = color;
        }
        function changeBack(color){
            document.getElementById("miTabla").style.backgroundColor = color;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>Tabla de ejemplo</header>
    <table id="miTabla" border="2">
           <tr>
            <td>changeFont</td>
            <td onclick="changeFont('#FF0000');">red</td>
            <td onclick="changeFont('#FFFF00');">yellow</td>
            <td onclick="changeFont('#0000FF');">blue</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>changeBack</td>
            <td onclick="changeBack('#FFFFFF');">white</td>
            <td onclick="changeBack('#808080');">gray</td>
            <td onclick="changeBack('#000000');">black</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```